# Something had me do or Something had me doing something else?

Tags: present-participles, bare-infinitive, causative-verbs

I’m edit­ing a short story and I’ve stum­bled upon a prob­lem. I 
fre­quently use struc­tures like:

- Agony had my in­sides **con­vuls­ing**.
- De­feat had me **slump­ing** into a chair.
- Fear had my body **shak­ing**.

My ques­tion is, are these sen­tences cor­rect as writ­ten, or should they 
be writ­ten like this:

- Agony had my in­sides **con­vulse**.
- De­feat had me **slump** into a chair.
- Fear had my body **shake**.

Comment: In the second set, "had" doesn't work for me. I'd use "made" or something similar.

Comment: They are fine and the structure is pretty common. Why are you unsure of their correctness? Can you explain further?

Comment: Like I said, I use structures like Defeat had me slumping into a chair, so HAVE/HAD + Person/Thing+ Verb -ing form. Then I looked over the causative structure which is Causative Verb + Person/Thing + Verb (infinitive form), and I wasn't sure anymore which version was correct.

Comment: If you could find two versions, then how would you suspect one of them may not be correct? As I always ask here: Why should only one of alternatives be correct? They may or may not mean the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sᴜᴍ­ᴍᴀʀʏ

No, you shouldn’t swap the verb com­ple­ment from con­tin­u­ous 
form to its in­fini­tive form as you’ve sug­gested do­ing.
The change in as­pect would sub­tly al­ter the mean­ing:
they are not equiv­a­lent. 
If you did that, it would mean some­thing else subtly different.

Look at it this way:

- If *your mother **had you eat** your peas*, then that means she made you eat the
  peas, and they are are now eaten and done with.
- In con­trast, if *she **had you eat­ing** your peas*, she did some­thing to
  leave you in the state that you were (*still!*) eat­ing your peas, not that
  you had al­ready fin­ished do­ing so as in the orig­i­nal.

## Tech­ni­cal De­tails

When you use the verb *have* in a tran­si­tive way with an ob­ject and then
an­other com­ple­ment, that com­ple­ment ex­presses ei­ther (1) the ac­tion that the
sub­ject causes the ob­ject to take, or (2) the re­sult­ing con­di­tion of the ob­ject
caused by that sub­ject.

All this falls under OED sense #28 for the verb *have*: [<sup>[*paywalled link*]</sup>](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/84705)

> 28. *transitive*. With complement expressing an action or state caused by the subject.
>       Also with *will* or *would* indicating volition or requirement; cf. **will** *v*.¹ 40a.

Both your ex­am­ples are of this sort. The dif­fer­ence be­tween them is that
the first uses a **bare in­fini­tive** for its com­ple­ment, while the sec­ond uses
the progressive *‑ing* form for its com­ple­ment. Here are ex­am­ples from
each of the OED’s four sub­­senses for sense 2, vary­ing by the type of com­ple­ment:

1. *He had the guns counted.* (com­ple­ment is past par­tici­ple)
2. *She had them in tears.* (other com­ple­ment)
3. *What would you have me do? / I'll have you know.* (com­ple­ment is bare in­fini­tive)
4. *He had them rolling in the aisles.* (com­ple­ment is *‑ing* verb)

Both your ex­am­ples are ***non-fi­nite* verb phrases/clauses**, but they mean
slightly dif­fer­ent things, cor­re­spond­ing to the third and fourth OED
sub­senses for sense 28.

The third sub­sense is this one:

> - c. With bare infinitive (formerly also †*to*-infinitive, †*at* and infinitive) as complement.
>
>   (a) To in­duce, pre­vail upon, or com­pel (a per­son) or to suc­ceed in caus­ing
>     (a thing) to do some­thing; e.g. *what would you have me do?* Also (in
>     weak­ened sense): to cause or set (a per­son) to do some­thing for one. Cf.
>     **get** *v.* 28a.
>    Also oc­ca­sion­ally with pas­sive in­fini­tive: to
>     cause or com­pel to un­dergo the spec­i­fied ac­tion; cf. sense 28a.
>    See
>     also *I'll have you know* at Phrases 3b.

In sim­pler words, it means to “make” some­one do the spec­i­fied ac­tion. So
*she had me eat peas* could have been writ­ten *she made me eat peas*
in­stead. Those two mean the same thing.

The fourth sub­sense is the type be­ing used in your three orig­i­nal
sen­tences:

> - d. With present par­tici­ple as com­ple­ment. To com­pel, in­duce, ar­range for (a
>     per­son or thing) to be do­ing some­thing; e.g. *he had them rolling in the
>     aisles.* Cf. **get** *v.* 31b.

So the dif­fer­ence here is one of as­pect. The (c) case is a bare in­fin­tive
so there is no con­tin­u­ous as­pect in­volved.  The (d) case by us­ing the *‑ing* form
of the verb uses the con­tin­u­ous as­pect to con­vey that the ac­tion was an on­go­ing one,
that it was in progress.

Here for the record are the first two sub­senses from the OED:

> - a. With past par­tici­ple as com­ple­ment. To cause or ar­range for the
>     spec­i­fied ac­tion to be per­formed on (a per­son or thing); e.g. *he had the
>     guns counted.* Cf. **get** *v.* 29a(a).
> - b. With com­ple­ment. To bring into the spec­i­fied state or con­di­tion, esp.
>     de­lib­er­ately; to cause to be­come; to make, ren­der; e.g. *she had them in
>     tears*. Cf. **get** *v.* 26a(a).

Answer (score 0):

*Agony had my insides convulsing.* This is normal.

*Agony had my insides convulse.* This (a) personifies Agony and (b) seems to imply a third party who was instructed by Agony to cause your insides to convulse - perhaps by administering poison?

Comment: Try and include some authentic references to support and strengthen the argument, though.